# Problem understanding fermion zero modes in Mirror Symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

Fermion zero modes are discussed in the context of the 2d axial R-anomaly in the Mirror Symmetry monograph but with the absence of some details. On page 296, a toy model is presented, with the action 
\begin{equation}
S=\int_{T^2}d^2z(i\bar{\psi}_+D_z\psi_++i\bar{\psi}_-D_\bar{z}\psi_-).
\end{equation}
On the following page it is claimed that the number of $\psi_-$ zero modes is equal to the number of $\bar{\psi}_+$ zero modes, and the number of $\bar{\psi}_-$ zero modes is equal to the number of ${\psi}_+$ zero modes. Why is this the case?

It seems to me that it has something to do with the fact that e.g., $D_z\bar{\psi}_+=\overline{D_{\bar{z}}}\bar{\psi}_+$, but I cannot understand why.